# Jenkins Pipeline to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, excel, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline which runs sql counts everyday as part of regression testing, I would like to be able to export the results of each build into an excel document where the results can be stored and compared, is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is an IDE used to connect to many different RDBMS (it is not a database) and appears to be irrelevant to the question so I've removed that tag. If it is relevant then you should [edit] the question to include it and explain why you need to include that specific IDE in your pipeline.

Comment: You could use our CLI utility Oracle SQLcl to create CSV files (based on results of SQL you run), adding that to your pipeline wouldn't be very expensive in terms of time/resources.